# Reading details from txt file in php

Tags: php, ubuntu, authentication, ssh, ssh2

I have a txt file where my configuration detail is stored.

**confg.txt**

```
10.xx.xx.xx
abc
P@ssword1
/home/user/myfolder
```

I want this file detail for connecting to remote machine.

```
<?php
$myfile="confg.txt";
$line=file($myfile);
$server   = "$line[0]"; 
$username = "$line[1]"; 
$password = "$line[2]"; 

$connection = ssh2_connect($server, 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password);
 ssh2_exec($connection,"bash hello.sh");
?>
```

When I am running the php file, I am getting the error:

> PHP Warning:  ssh2_auth_password(): Authentication failed for abc 
>   using password

It seems it can not able read and fetch the file correctly. 
Since, I also tried with this, but got same error. So nothing related to password , may be not able to take input properly.

```
$server   = "10.xx.xx.xx"; 
$username = "$line[1]"; 
$password = "P@ssword1";
```

Please suggest me suitable approach to feeding detail from txt file. Thanks!!

Comment: *$password = $line[2];* will correct it

Comment: @Pradeep, I am still getting same error

Comment: @Pradeep, Can you please check my updated question?

Comment: $line = explode("\n", file_get_contents($myfile));